# Can we use Postmark mail service provider in laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, postmark

I'm getting following error when using postmark(mail service provider) in **laravel 5.4**

Exception:-

> 'ErrorException' with message 'Illegal offset type in unset' in
>   ...vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1057

Please help

Comment: Please post your code where you are using the Postmark mail provider so we can help you locate your problem!

Answer (score 0):

This will fix it:

https://github.com/Snowfire/Laravel-Postmark-Driver/issues/11

"I hotfixed this by replacing by changing its usage on the line no. 36 of the file PostmarkServiceProvider.php, which was

$this->app['swift.mailer'] = $this->app->share(function ($app) use ($postmark) {

to

$this->app->singleton('swift.mailer', function ($app) use ($postmark) {"

It's not ideal, but it looks like the package is not being maintained.

Also, upgrading to Laravel 5.5 brings compatibility problems with the new version of OpenBuildings\postmark which might be more easily worked around by using SMTP with Postmark.